# Reading lines interactively in bash

Tags: bash, readline

I am using the following code to take input from user interactively, 
thus allowing the user to make changes to the input without deleting the entire line.

```
#! /bin/bash

while :
do
    echo -n "prompt# "
    read -e input
done
```

Problem:

It also allows me to delete the "prompt#", which I don't want to happen.
I don't want the "prompt# " to be deleted by the user in any case.
I've tried using various options in `read` command but can't figure it out.
How can I achieve this?

Edit:
The sequence of events that led to the problem:
1. I ran the above script and entered "hello".
2. Then I moved my cursor to 'e' in "hello" and "pressed and held"      backspace for some time which resulted in the deletion of the "prompt# "
3. If you don't type any characters it works fine and the prompt is not    deleted but if you enter even a white space or any character and then  press the backspace then it messes the prompt.

Take a look at the snapshot below.
**Snapshot[image: bash readline prompt deletion]**:

Comment: You should use `read`'s builtin prompt support, or you're on your own. `read -p 'prompt# ' -e input`.

Comment: @4ae1e1: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much....

Comment: @4ae1e1 - make it an answer!

Comment: I agree with using `read -p`. But even with OP's current implementation, it should not allow deleting the lines echoed by `echo`, unless user enters some ANSI control characters...

Comment: @anishsane I'd like to claim that it shouldn't, but I can't because it's highly reproducible (and I vaguely remember running into this problem before myself). I can reproduce on latest stable (4.3.42, readline 6.3.8) and testing (4.4-beta with bundled readline). Maybe it's a bug in readline. Note that there's no "deleting the lines" involved; you can delete (or move) to the beginning of the current line, that's it.

Comment: Enter `read -p prompt var`. Then press <kbd>Left</kbd> It will move the cursor over prompt... This behavior is same as that seen with `echo -n` mechanism.

Comment: @anishsane: Actually I accidentally "pressed and held" backspace and saw that the prompt got deleted, which I didn't wanted.

Comment: @anishsane Not here. I don't have any issue when using `-p`.

Comment: Oh, by the way, everything I said (i.e., problem with `echo` then `read`, and no problem with `read -p`) was tested on Terminal.app and iTerm2 on OS X, with bash on OS X and bash on Ubuntu through ssh.

Comment: @anishsane: I've added some more details that led to the problem. Also snapshot of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From 4ae1e1's comment:

You should use read's builtin prompt support, or you're on your own.

```
read -p 'prompt# ' -e input
```

Comment: Off topic: Many times, some user posts the answer as comment & then forgets about it. But the question does not get closed, because there is no answer. & I don't want to steal credit of that user. So, marking it as community wiki is a good idea.